# Sequence of servlet calling

Tags: java, html, servlets

Hi I have an HTMl form that auto-generates a captcha image and then an audio clip is generated automatically according to the captcha genenrated. the form looks as follows.

```
<div class="formRow">
            <div class="field">
                <img style="margin-left:91px; margin-top:-6px;" class="image" src="http://www.abc.com/captchaServlet">
            </div>
            </div>
             <div class="formRow">
                  <div class="field">
                  <audio style="margin-left:91px;" controls="controls">
  <source id="audiowav" src="http://www.abc.com/getSound" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
                      </div>
             </div>
```

When the captcha is generated then I store the captcha code in the session as an attribute and then when i have to generate audio file then i get the attribute from session and generate it. But what happens sometimes is that when i refresh the page the audio tag servlet gets called first i.e. http://www.abc.com/getSound gets called before http://www.abc.com/captchaServlet does so the image and audio dont match.  So i want to make sure that first http://www.abc.com/captchaServlet gets called from the form and then 
http://www.abc.com/getSound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no guarantee that will happen because that is the browser which is deciding in which order to load the resources, which is browser dependent and you can't really force it to follow a specific order as such.

You should have your captcha work in a different way. Maybe have the actual code generated by the page and put in the session, and then the `getSound` and `captchaServlet` generating the respective sound or image from the code in the session?

Comment: But how do I make sure that the code generated goes into the session even before the servlets get called. What if again the servlets get called first and then the code is put into the session!!

Comment: If the session variable is initialised by the page itself, not by the image or audio generated, you have the guarantee. Because the browser first gets the page and then after parsing its HTML sees which resources it needs to get (images, css etc.), at which point you would already have a new captcha code generated, which will be the same for both the image and audio.

Comment: Ok yeah I got it. It's actually a good idea. But this makes my code very vulnerable and exposed. But that's a new issue now I guess. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Well it depends how you see it. If your user is logging in with a username/password you are storing the state in the session in the same way. Everything works that way, so hopefully its not vulnerable :). If you structure things properly (for example putting the captcha code in the same class, and the different servlets/pages calling it) you shouldn't have design problems.

Comment: Well yeah I see your point. I guess I should start making changes in the structure now. Security is a big issue with my current project.

Comment: If you want you could also consider how most modern CAPTCHAs work (like ReCaptcha). It is a bit more complicated, because they work mostly using AJAX or Javascript to load the contents of all the snippet within your outer `<div class="formRow">`, so essentially you still have a page serving that snippet, which initialises the captcha code and in it there would be the image and audio resources.  But this approach is a bit more complex.

Comment: I call image and sound from  different source tags in in my HTMl form, and when first servlet is called a new image is generated and what was happening was that sometimes a sound servlet was getting called before and image servlet and an old wav file was being uploaded in the form so is it possible that I put a check in soudn servlet that if sound file is alredy existing wait for the session attribute to refresh like e.g.
File mp2 = new File( ./generatedCaptchaSounds/"+aud+".wav");
       while(mp2.exists()){    aud=request.getSession().getAttribute("captcha").toString();
       }

Comment: what i mean is I want to put a while loop to check if the new captcha code has been put in session which wont happen until mp2.exists() returns false. so i wanted to ask if the two servlets will be running simultaneously?? which would make the sound servlet wait until the captcha attribute in the session has been modified in the image servlet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19708/discussion-between-jbx-and-kapil-chhattani)